# How Can I Install Dragon Ball Fighter Z using wine?

Tags: software-installation

I am Always getting errors when I am trying to play it.., Please Help, how do i install dragon ball fighter z for free without any errors?
I'v tried so many times?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 64 bit

Please Find away?

Comment: Are you getting errors when you install it or when you play the game? Most likely no one can help unless you edit your question and include details, especially the exact error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer you cannot.
Check the site for details has this can change with time.
[Winehq](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=18704)

There are some people playing it with Proton, but even they are getting several issues.
Check the link: [protondb](https://www.protondb.com/app/678950).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I get errors when I play the game

Comment: It is normal since you are not playing in its natural environment, Windows. But has users try it on Linux better solutions to run it on Linux may appear.